# Compact and continuous imbedding of Hilbert spaces.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $B_i$ be Hilbert spaces with the continuous inclusions

$B_1 \rightarrow B_2 \rightarrow B_3.$

further assume that $B_1$ is compactly imbedded in $B_2$. Then I need to show that given any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $C_{\epsilon} >0$ such that for all $u \in B_1$

$||u||_{B_2} \leq \epsilon||u||_{B_1}+C_{\epsilon}||u||_{B_3}.$

Answer (score 2):

Rewritten more clearly on the request of @am_11235... . I thank them for their assistance in helping improve the answer to this question. The original answer was *incorrect*.

This question is actually exercise 6.12 of Brezis' Functional Analysis. It is attributed to J.L. Lions.

---

We work by contradiction. Suppose for an $\epsilon>0$, we have that no $C_\epsilon$ works. Then, we have a sequence $v_m \in B_1$ such that $$\|v_m\|_{B_2} >\epsilon \|v_m\|_{B_1} + m\|v_m\|_{B_3}$$ (contradict the statement for all natural number values of $C_\epsilon$). Observe that $v_m \neq 0$ for all $m$ (as an element of $B_2$), because such an inequality cannot hold for the zero vector.

Let $u_m = \frac{v_m}{\|v_m\|_2}$. If we divide the above inequality by $\|v_m\|_2$, we get $$
1 >\epsilon\frac{\|v_m\|_{1}}{\|v_m\|_{2}} + m\frac{\|v_m\|_{B_3}}{\|v_m\|_{B_2}}
$$
Which becomes $$
1 >\epsilon \|u_m\|_{B_1} +m \|u_m\|_{B_3}
$$
with the knowledge that $||u_m||_{B_2} = 1$ for all $m$.

(The error in the previous edit was the normalization I used here. It led to some typos down the line).

---

Observe that $\|u_m\|_{B_1} < \frac 1{\epsilon}$ for all $m$. Therefore, $\{u_m\}$ is a bounded sequence in $B_1$.

As the inclusion map $B_1 \to B_2$ is compact, there exists a convergent subsequence in $B_2$, given by $u_{m_k}$. Say that $u_{m_k} \to u$ in $B_2$.

As the inclusion map from $B_2$ to $B_3$ is continuous, one sees that $u_{m_k} \to u$ in $B_3$ as well.

---

However, let's go back to the inequality with $u_{m_k}$ used instead of $u_m$ : $$
1 >\epsilon \|u_{m_k}\|_{B_1} +m_k\|u_{m_k}\|_{B_3}
$$

Now, if $u \neq 0$, then $\|u\| \neq 0$. In particular, we can find $K$ larger enough such that $\|u_{m_k}\| > \frac{\|u\|}{2}$ for all $k>K$. But then, $m_k\|u_{m_k}\|_{B_3} > m_k \frac{\|u\|}{2} \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$. This contradicts the inequality.

It follows that $u = 0$.

However, we also had $u_{m_k} \to u$ in $B_2$. This is a problem, since $\|u_{m_k} - 0\| = \|u_{m_k}\| = 1$ for all $k$, so there is no way that $u_{m_k} \to 0$ in $B_2$.

Finally, the contradiction is complete, and the sequence of $u_k$ cannot exist. Thus, there is a $C_{\epsilon}>0$ such that the proposed inequality holds for all $u$.

Comment: Sorry for reviving an old topic , but by continuous $B_1\hookrightarrow B_2$ isn't the inequality $||u_{m_k}||_{B_2}\geq c||u_{m_k}||_{B_1}$ supposed to be the other way around ?

Comment: @am_11235... No apologies required! Thank you for asking. I'll have to read this answer and get back to you, it's *exactly* six years to the day since I wrote this answer.

Comment: @am_11235... I had made a terrible mistake in the scaling region. When I recognized that, it was easy to write the proof. I hope there is no problem now. Thanks once again.